# An example of a finite group with some specific permutable subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, examples

The following question is about finite groups.

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H, K \leqslant G$. We say that $H$ permutes with $K$ if $HK = KH$ and in this case $HK \leqslant G$.

The Symbol $\pi (G)$ denotes the set of all primes that divides the order of $G$.

I need to find an example of a finite group $G$, preferably $G$ is solvable, such that the following properties hold:

(1) $G$ has a subnormal subgroup $K$.

(2) There exists a prime $p \in \pi (G)$ such that $K$ does not permute with any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

(3) $G$ has a set of nilpotent Hall subgroups $\{H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n\}$ such that $\pi (G) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n \pi (H_i)$ and $(|H_i|,|H_j|) =1$ for $i \neq j$ and $i, j = 1, 2, \dots n$.

(4) $K$ permutes with $H_i$ for all $H_i \in \{H_1, H_2, \dots, H_n\}$.

Remark: Condition (2) implies that $|\pi (H_i)| \geqslant 2$ for at least one $i$.

Comment: Could you say something about why you need to find such an example? At first sight this looks like a very arbitrary list of properties. Also how far have you got with your search?

Comment: @DerekHolt Here is what I Know: $|\pi (G)|>2$, this is clear by the above remark.

Comment: @DerekHolt $K$ is not nilpotent. Suppose $K$ is nilpotent and let $\pi = \pi (H_i)$. Then $K = K_\pi 
K_{\pi^\prime}$ and by (4), $K_{\pi^\prime}H_i = K_{\pi^\prime} K_\pi H_i = KH_i$. As 
$K_{\pi^\prime}$ is subnormal Hall of $K_{\pi^\prime}H_i$, then $K_{\pi^\prime} \lhd 
K_{\pi^\prime}H_i$. So, $K = K_\pi K_{\pi^\prime}$ permutes with every all Sylow subgroups of $H_i$ 
which are Sylow subgroups of $G$ for all $i$. This contradicts (2).

Comment: @DerekHolt I used GAP and search the groups of the orders from 1 to 1000. Also, I have searched some subgroups 
which are divisible by 4 primes and some which are divisible by 5 primes. But I did not have any 
luck with those.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is a research by that works some problems involving permutability that deal with the set 
mentioned in (3). https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/jgth.2015.18.issue-2/jgth-2014-0045/jgth-2014-0045.xml

Comment: @DerekHolt Recently, I submitted a research paper that have some theorems dealing with subnormal subgroups 
permuting with the set mentioned in (3). The referee asked me to provide an example with the above 
conditions for the sake of strengthen the results. More precisely, to show that condition (1) and(4) does not imply that $K$ permutes with at least one Sylow $p$-subgroup for each prime $p \in \pi (G) $. He said that there exist such examples.